# Dealing with a password with special characters in Ansible

Tags: shell, ansible, special-characters

I'm trying to run an ansible playbook with the ansible_ssh_pass option to connect to the destination server.

```
ansible-playbook test-playbook.yml -i hosts -u daniel --extra-vars "{"ansible_ssh_pass":"u5!vuL!<35Lf?<>n'x"}"
```

The problem is that the password has special characters.
I tried saving it using.

```
"password\'s"
"password"
"\"password\""
```

Any idea how can I save the password?

Comment: Did you try encoding it as JSON would?

Comment: Same error using the JSON coding

Comment: `'{"ansible_ssh_pass":"u5!vuL!<35Lf?<>n\'x"}'`? (Using single quote for the whole JSON value the double quote for strings inside the JSON and escaping the single quotes in the JSON)

Answer (score 5):

Finally figured this one out for a password changing script that couldn't use [vars_prompts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_prompts.html).

For my `bash` program that was running `ansible` I needed to first get the password from a user via `read` then do the following:

1. Convert the bad string into `base64` and save to `b64_pass`
2. Pass `b64_pass` as `b64_ansible_ssh_pass` extra arg
3. Use `set_fact` to set `ansible_ssh_pass` and use `b64decode` filter on extra arg `b64_ansible_ssh_pass`

Short example testba.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p -s "Enter ssh password: " ssh_pass

# Convert input or var to base64
b64_pass=$(printf '%s' "$ssh_pass" | base64)

# Run ansible command
ansible-playbook test.yml -m shell -a "echo OK" -e "b64_ansible_ssh_pass='$b64_pass'" -v
```

Playbook test.yml:

```
- hosts: all

  # Assign ansible_ssh_pass in vars OR below in task with set_fact
  vars:
    ansible_ssh_pass: "{{ b64_ansible_ssh_pass | b64decode }}"

  tasks:
    # Assign ansible_ssh_pass in task with set_fact
    - name: Set ssh pass
      set_fact:
        ansible_ssh_pass: "{{ b64_ansible_ssh_pass | b64decode }}"
      no_log: true

    - shell: echo hi
```

If you need to pass a password var into the user module

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p -s "Enter ssh password: " ssh_pass

# Convert input or var to base64
b64_pass=$(printf '%s' "$ssh_pass" | base64)

# Run ansible command
ansible <hosts_to_run_on> -m shell -a "echo OK" -e "new_pass=$b64_pass"
```

Then in your playbook

```
- hosts: all
  vars:
    my_new_pass: "{{ new_pass | b64decode }}" 
  tasks:
    user:
      name: "NewUser"
      password: "{{ my_new_pass }}"
```

Answer (score 4):

Probably a little late but the exact solution to your specific problem is:

```
ansible-playbook test-playbook.yml -i hosts -u daniel --extra-vars ansible_ssh_pass=$'"u5!vuL!<35Lf?<>n\'x"'
```

The shell treats `$'<string>'` specially and escapes the single quote inside (see the backslash)

The outermost double quotes are necessary so that jinja2 template engine does not get confused inside ansible.

That being said, it is quite a bad idea to run the command like this for at least two reasons:

- It's not secure. Anyone with access to listing processes on the machine or to your shell history will be able to see the password.
- It's not flexible. Ansible extra variables provided on the command line have the highest precedence. If you add an other host in your inventory with a different ssh password, you won't be able to differentiate the two passwords.

For the first problem, and if you are sure you will only have one machine (or the same password everywhere), you could ask for the password interactively with vars_prompt for example (http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_prompts.html)

The best approach solving both issues is to add the password using vault encryption to your inventory for the particular host. You then provide the overall vault password interactively (--ask-vault-pass) or through a well secured vault password file (--vault-password-file=) when you call the playbook.

Answer (score 0):

I know that for ansible-vault you can specify a password in a file, I am assuming that this would also work in this case, though I am not positive.

```
ansible-playbook test-playbook.yml -i hosts -u daniel --extra-vars ansible_ssh_pass=/path/to/file.txt
```

Comment: If your using linux you could setup and ssh key for the user you want and bypass the password altogether

Comment: We are not allowed to share keys between the server. The idea is to do the connection using user/pass.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the singe quote special char, you can do single quotes around the rest and it should work:

```
ansible-playbook test-playbook.yml -i hosts -u daniel -e ansible_ssh_pass='u5!vuL!<35Lf?<>nx'
```

Answer (score 0):

1、if ansible ansible_ssh_pass Has special characters

```
[test]
192.168.1.1 ansible_ssh_user=network ansible_ssh_pass="'6j#@D@vcsA4'"
```