# How to safely pass variables that may contain special characters to a docker-compose file in Ansible

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ansible, jinja2

I am currently using an ansible script to deploy a docker-compose file (using the docker_service module), which sets a series of environment variables which are read by the .NET Core service running inside the docker container, like this:

```
(...)
environment:
   - Poller:Username={{ poller_username }}
   - Poller:Password={{ poller_password }}
(...)
```

The variables for poller_username and poller_password are being loaded from an Ansible Vault (which will be moved to a Hashicorp Vault eventually), and are interpolated into the file with no problem.

However, I have come across a scenario where this logic fails: the user has a '$' in the middle of his password. This means that instead of the environment variable being set to 'abc$123' it's instead set to 'abc', causing my application to fail.

Upon writing a debug command, I get the password output to the console correctly.  If I do `docker exec <container_name> env` I get the wrong password.

Is there a Jinja filter I can use to ensure the password is compliant with docker-compose standards? It doesn't seem viable to me to guarantee the password will never have a $.

EDIT: `{{ poller_password | replace("$","$$") }}` works, but this isn't a very elegant solution to have in, potentially, every variable I use in the docker-compose module.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47101789/dealing-with-a-password-with-special-characters-in-ansible

Comment: Try encapsulating the jinja2 templates with quotes: ```...="{{ poller_username }}"```

Comment: Encapsulating with quotes won't work, as the environment variables themselves will get interpreted as if they have "", i.e. the password will be assumed to be the 9 character password "abc$123".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this particular scenario, the `{{ poller_password | replace("$","$$") }}` solution seems to be inevitable. Thankfully, it appears to be the only case that requires this caution.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar situation was not a $ but some other character, end up using

```
something: !unsafe "{{ variable }}"
```

couldn't find a better way.

Comment: this unfortunately doesn't solve the problem, as it is specific to docker-compose's escaping